# spring hibernate integration error , propery conversion error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

i am using mysql as my database,the entities are created and the persistence.xml is created . But i am getting an exception related to creating beans in beanfactory, while running/deploying the web application .

spring version is 4.0.6.RELEASE

hibernate version is 4.3.5.Final

spring jpa version is 1.6.2.RELEASE

**root-context.xml file is**

```
    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.sarathraj.springdata" />

   <bean id="dataSource"
class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springdb" />
<property name="username" value="root" />
<property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>

  <bean id="jpaventor" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" >
    <property name="database" value="MYSQL"/>  
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>  
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>  
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>  
   </bean>



  <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
   <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.sarathraj.springdata.entity"></property>
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
   <property name="jpaProperties" ref="jpaventor"></property>
   <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="SpringMVCExample"/> 
  </bean>



   <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
   </bean> -->
   <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>  
  <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>  

   <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
   </bean>
```

**persistance.xml**

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="SpringMVCExample">
        <class>com.sarathraj.springdata.entity.Person</class>
        <class>com.sarathraj.springdata.entity.Role</class>
        <class>com.sarathraj.springdata.entity.Blog</class>
        <class>com.sarathraj.springdata.entity.Item</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**exception is**

```
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' to required type 'java.util.Properties' for property 'jpaProperties'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' to required type 'java.util.Properties' for property 'jpaProperties'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' to required type 'java.util.Properties' for property 'jpaProperties'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:263)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
    ... 40 more
Aug 07, 2014 5:45:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' to required type 'java.util.Properties' for property 'jpaProperties'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:618)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' to required type 'java.util.Properties' for property 'jpaProperties'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:198)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:470)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:277)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:79)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:71)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1572)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' to required type 'java.util.Properties' for property 'jpaProperties'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] to required type [java.util.Properties] for property 'jpaProperties': PropertyEditor [org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.PropertiesEditor] returned inappropriate value of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:263)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
    ... 40 more
```

## here is an example entity

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity 
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;


    private String name;

    private String password;

    private String email;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable
    private List<Role> roles;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person")
    private List<Blog> blogs;



    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public List<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public List<Blog> getBlogs() {
        return blogs;
    }

    public void setBlogs(List<Blog> blogs) {
        this.blogs = blogs;
    }





}
```

Really appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a wrong object for the property 'jpaProperties'

```
<property name="jpaProperties" ref="jpaventor"></property>
```

The jpaventor bean is of type `HibernateJpaVendorAdapter`. But the jpaProperties property epects a bean of type `java.util.Properties`

Passing correct object reference will solve your issue

Comment: thanks , its worked  !!! when i given as    '<property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaventor"></property>'